# How to select data from table on the basis of other

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables T1 and T2. Here T1 contains blogs and T2 contains list of users who liked post.

T1 database schema post_id,post

**AND**

T2 database schema post_id,user_id

I want to select only those posts that is at least 10 users liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.post_id, T1.post, COUNT(T2.user_id]) as Total
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.post_id = T2.post_id 
GROUP BY T1.post_id, T1.post 
HAVING Total >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can group your selection and then use [`having`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
SELECT posts.*, COUNT(likes.id) as likesCount
FROM posts, likes
GROUP BY posts.id HAVING (likesCount >= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

In table **T2** the post_id which occurs more than 10 is your desired post, so you can pick the posts which have post_id occurring at atleast 10 rows in your table **T2**

Comment: can you elaborate this with a query please

Comment: select post_id 
from T2
Group by post_id 
having count>=10

And then you can use the post_id's from this query to select those posts from T1

This isn't the exact query, but the query you'll be writing will be somewhat similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a subselect?

```
SELECT post_id,COUNT(post_id) AS count,
(SELECT post FROM T1 where post_id=T2.post_id) AS post
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING count >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

With purpose to have best performance and avoid "cartesian product" use `join`, like this:

```
SELECT p.post_id, COUNT(l.user_id) AS TotalLikesCount
FROM posts AS p
JOIN likes AS l ON p.post_id = l.post_id
GROUP BY p.post_id
HAVING TotalLikesCount >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select posts using join.

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post, count(pl.user_id) as likes 
FROM `post` as p
join post_likes as pl on p.post_id = pl.post_id

where 1 group by pl.post_id
having likes >= 10;
```